# gprof output is empty

Tags: c, gcc, gprof

Using gprof 2.28 and gcc 6.3.0 in Ubuntu 17.04 on a variety of sample programs I get empty output for every category. If I run gprof -i on one example program I get:

```
1 histogram record
2 call-graph records
0 basic-block count records
```

My compilation looks something like this:

```
cc -g -c sem_test.c -pg
cc -o sem_test sem_test.o -lpthread -pg
```

Or this:

```
gcc -g3 -O0 -Wall -std=gnu99 -pg -fprofile-arcs -fno-inline -fno-reorder-functions sem_test.c -o sem_test -lpthread -pg
```

Both have the same results.

I notice that my gmon.out file is only 687 bytes which seems low.

Comment: I bet your `sem_test.c` does almost nothing, or that what it does is almost exclusively waiting for something from the system, like a semaphore or I/O. *gprof* can only take samples every .01 seconds, which is like every 10^7 instructions, and that only when the program is actually computing, not waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a glibc bug/limitation:

- [-pg -pie doesn't work](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22284)

If you cannot install a fixed glibc, you can link with `-no-pie` to disable PIE.  Your toolchain probably enables PIE automatically.

Comment: I had to specify `-fno-pie` instead. gcc 4.4.5 on i386 here.